# Can fread() detect null character?

Tags: c

Using C, can the function **fread** be used to read a null terminated string?

I have to read a file that starts with an ip as 4 unsigned chars followed by an integer describing the number of null terminated strings. After that, I need to read the strings until the last one before another ip list starts.

I greatly appreciate your help

**Edit:**
I need to detect the null character and stop fread from continuing

Comment: Note: to read a file that "starts with an ip as 4 unsigned chars", insure the file is opened in _binary_ mode.  Then cope with potential variant lines endings in the string portion of the file, should they come up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to answer this question is: "sort of".  Will `fread()` read the null terminated string? Absolutely, `fread()` just reads data out of the file as bytes. But, you can't ask it to read the next null-terminated string, because it doesn't know or care about strings.

You'll need to do some processing after the read to determine where the strings end and how many you've read.  This is probably a decent strategy -- read in some of the file, check how many strings you read, and read again if needed.  This does complicate things a little, though, like if there is more data after the strings you didn't want to read yet.

A simpler approach, would be to just loop using `fgetc()`, something like:

```
for (int n = 0; n < strings_to_read; n++) {
    int ch, i = 0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != '\0' && ch != EOF) {
        str[n][i++] = ch;
    }
    str[n][i] = '\0';
}
```

Minus some extra tweaks to make sure the memory is allocated right, EOF is handled correctly, etc., that sort of method will allow you to read the strings fairly easily.

Answer (score 5):

`fread` does not stop reading at any delimiter, `'\0'` or otherwise. It attempts to read the exact number of bytes requested, and will only stop earlier if it encounters end-of-file or a read error.

On POSIX 2008 conforming systems, the `getdelim` function provides an easy way to "read until `'\0'`". Otherwise, you're stuck with a loop calling `getc` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [*FatalError*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25895873/694576) please find below a slightly more efficient (in terms of statements) version also handling possible errors that may be introduced by reading or a corrupted file (in terms of the OP's specifications):

```
for (size_t n = 0; n < strings_to_read; ++n) 
{
  int ch = EOF;

  do
  {
     size_t i = 0;

     ch = fgetc(fp);
     /* Error handling: */
     if (EOF == ch)
     {
       /* Getting EOF means end of file (unexpected, from the OP's specifications) or an error. */
       if (ferror(fp))
       {
         perror("fgetc() failed");
       }
       else
       {
         fprintf("Unexpected end of file.\n");
       }

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     str[n][i++] = ch;
  } while ('\0' != ch)
}
```

Comment: Nice complete answer and good use of `size_t` and detecting `EOF` reason. +1 (Bit of a mystery as why `int ch = -1;` vs. `int ch = EOF;` vs `int ch;`)

Comment: @chux: Why not just `int ch;`? To have everything properly initialised. Althought it's redundant here one loses nothing, but gains sort of clarity as no-one knows who's finger are next at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `fread` will simply read bytes, including null-terminators, out of a file until it reaches the end of the file.

Edit:
As for stopping at a null-terminator the other answers already address your edit so I won't re-hash it!

Comment: That's true. But can I read each null terminated string without knowing its size?

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. The "yes" and the following sentence actually contradict one another.

Comment: You cannot read up to '\0' and then stop. fread() fills a buffer till it's full or file ends. It has no concept of line separator. You need to implement you own separation, looking for '\0' in the buffer

Comment: It does answer the *original* post (the bit they marked as "edit" is an edit). Can fread *read* a null-terminator? Yes it can. That's why I answered "yes". The OP did not originally ask for it to stop reading after the \0. He/she even annotated their edit!